# Geoseries is converted to pandas.Series unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I was practicing [Intriduction of Geopandas's Getting Started](https://geopandas.org/getting_started/introduction.html). I followed the steps and found that the GeoSeries, created by `.boundary`, was converted to pandas.Series automatically when appending it to a GeoDataframe. The codes are listed:

```
import geopandas as gd

path_to_data = gd.datasets.get_path('nybb')
gdf = gd.read_file(path_to_data)

gdf['bd'] = gdf.boundary
print(gdf['bd'])
print(type(gdf['bd']))
```

The outputs:

```
0    MULTILINESTRING ((970217.022 145643.332, 97022...
1    MULTILINESTRING ((1029606.077 156073.814, 1029...
2    MULTILINESTRING ((1021176.479 151374.797, 1021...
3    MULTILINESTRING ((981219.056 188655.316, 98094...
4    MULTILINESTRING ((1012821.806 229228.265, 1012...
Name: bd, dtype: geometry
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

This seems not to be the case in the Introduction. I followed the installation instruction by trying `conda install geopandas` and `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas` to install it on Win-64 OS, which both have the same problem. I found some explanations about the GeoSeries will be converted to Series automatically when it doesn't contain geometry. But it's not my case. Have I done anything stupidly wrong on this most basic command...?

Comment: But each item has `dtype: geometry` as it should be.

Comment: It's still not GeoSeries, which is shown by ```type()```, so later it's problematic when calling ```.plot()``` to plot...

Comment: Updates: I just run the same codes on my MAC, which the packages were installed following the instructions as well, and it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

It is automatically converted to pandas dataframe unless you otherwise specify so.
[reference](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html#Creating-a-GeoDataFrame-from-a-DataFrame-with-coordinates)